# getting root directory from a class when called from a jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have to get the root directory of my project. If i write in a class as 
`System.getProperty("user.dir");` it is giving the exact result but when i put it in a method in same class and call that method from a jsp it is giving the incorrect result. Help me to resolve my issue.

Output from class:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testRootdir
```

Output when called from Jsp:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\bin
```

Required Output:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testRootdir
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Jens. Please let me know how to write/ where to write Server side code while posting question.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)